# How to add a minimum calculation in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

1 .[for example like this picture, I put in 30 kg of mass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl8oe.png) 2. [result 123000, because 30 x 4100 = 123000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea8fn.png) 3. [When entering 4 kg mass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRLR5.png) 4. [the result is 123000 . because min mass 30 kg. even though 4 x 4100 = 16400. I want to be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR96S.png)How to add a minimum calculation. for example, the price of cargo with a mass of 1 kg = 1000 and a minimum mass of 100 kg = 100000. So when I want to add 45 kg or less than 100 kg the result will still be 100,000 because the minimum mass is 100 kg. and if I enter a mass greater than 100 for example 101, then 101 x 1000 = 101000. I can only count on this source code but there is no minimum use of 100 kg. thank you

```
[
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /4000 + $model->admin_fee;
        $mass = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'];

        return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume;
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please edit it and make clearer.

Comment: ok has been updated

Comment: In your function  ..you want  $mass  = 100 when is <= 100?

Comment: no, I want $mass = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa']; //<=100 or with massa min 100 kg.  when Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'] = 45 kg or less than 100 kg the result will still be 100000. 45 x 1000 = 100000 because the minimum mass is 100 kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to parse it into variables so that it's easy to use

```
[
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {

        $panjang = Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'];
        $lebar = Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'];
        $tinggi = Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'];
        $volume = ($panjang * $lebar * $tinggi) / 4000;

        $rate = $model->rate;
        $rate_total = ($rate * $volume) + $model->admin_fee;

        $mass = Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'];
        $mass_min = 100;

        if ($mass_min < $mass) 
        {
           return $rate_total * $mass;
        } 
        else 
        {
           return $rate_total * $mass_min;
        }

     }
],
```